# Managing Heap Memory

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-management

I'm doing an special software for windows that needs to use two simultaneous heaps for a number of reasons.

I have read this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810603 and it describes how new heaps can be created and use them.

There is one heap that is created by the compiler called the default heap, which is the one we all use in C/C++ when we call new and malloc.

The question I have is, Is it possible to set a new heap as default heap so that all function calls that use memory allocations use this heap instead of the original one? Then when I need it switch back to the original

I know it looks tricky but I need to deal with this  to avoid some heap corruption during hardware interrupts.

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: You are 100% certain that all allocations performed during the switch will also be deallocated, and that no code will attempt to deallocate memory allocated before you switched? Very unlikely you can guarantee that.

Comment: It sounds broken. But C++ allows to override `new`, setting Allocators, etc. which can help to mitigate your problem.

Comment: David, yes the idea is to do it just for a function call in one thread of execution. Then switch back to normal. If during a malloc an interruption happens and I want to call malloc again within the trap funcion (on the user space context) some of the internals of the heap  in process may be corrupted.

Comment: knivil, thanks, the problem is I need to make sure that all function calls that  are using malloc or similar use a different heap. For instance Win32 apis.

Comment: The other threads will be calling malloc, free etc. at the same time as your special thread. You could impose a bespoke memory manager that behaves differently depending on the identify of the calling thread. It would surely be better to arrange that your code doesn't corrupt the heap. So, don't use heap allocation in a trap. That's the correct way to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm aware of multithread stuff and I can deal with it later on. The thing is this tricky solution I need is due to performance matters. I could wait until the current malloc finishes, but it is too slow.

I'm not saying the desing is good. It is just a proof of concept. I understand also there that the heap is set during the linkage phase as described in the article but anyway I wanted to give a try if it was possible.

Comment: The default heap is not created by the compiler; it is created by Windows during process initialization. The heap used by `malloc()` and related is not defined; a future version of the Visual C++ Runtime may use its own heap instead. If you have heap corruption, there is a bug somewhere in your code, and you need to fix that instead. Debugger *watch*points can help (Visual Studio seems to treat watchpoints and breakpoints identically, so you'll likely find them under breakpoints, but I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: Let me explain briefly what I want to do. I catch some interrupts in kernel space(driver) and modify some registers like instruction pointer on the process trap frame to jump to predefined location. But if the interruption happens during malloc (or whatever) I need  to keep the heap intact. Now, the new hacked code runs on the same thread for a little time to do some job I want, that is why I wanted to test the possibility to use a second heap to have the main heap intact. The same for the stack, I move the stack pointer and the base pointer to another location too, then have a safe stack.

Comment: Oh my, that's going to break *so* much stuff quite apart from memory allocation.  For one thing, a thread doesn't run only your code, it also runs operating system code; if you interrupt that, and run user code, and that user code calls *any* operating system function - well, it's just not going to be good.  So don't do that.  Threads are not interruptible in Windows.

Comment: Harry, good point. I will take a look to windows internals and seen what I can do.